# Database Calls Asynchronously

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asynchronous, webforms

I'm having a really difficult time wrapping my head around asynchronous. I've tried reading numerous questions/answers, forums etc.

I have to make about 50 calls to the database(I can't make a change to the database to return all in one call). So the answer is to use asynchronous so that I only have to wait for essentially the longest call. I am trying to do a simple logging of the time for 10 round trips.

My theory is that because I'm using two asynchronous tasks one in one method, and one in the calling method. The tasks look like they are completing but have not completed yet. here is my code.

I'm just logging the time it takes to complete the round trips for now, but the idea is to return the `List<ResultList>` in the future.

```
    protected async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Buildings> bldgList = new List<Buildings>(); 

            //lots of buildings here now.

            Stopwatch GetByOrg = new Stopwatch();
            lblorg.Text = await RunOrg(GetByOrg, bldgList);
        }

        async Task<string> RunOrg(Stopwatch getByOrg, List<Buildings> retVal)
        {
            getByOrg.Start();
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                foreach (Buildings b in bldgList)
                {
                    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => ExecuteOrg(b)));
                }
                //  var tasky = new Task()

            }
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
            getByOrg.Stop();
            return String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}", getByOrg.Elapsed.Hours, getByOrg.Elapsed.Minutes, getByOrg.Elapsed.Seconds, getByOrg.Elapsed.Milliseconds / 10);
        }
        async Task<List<ResultSet>> ExecuteOrg(Buildings b)
        {
            List<ResultSet> resulty = new List<ResultSet>();
            var asyncconn = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder("That Server Connection") { AsynchronousProcessing = true }.ToString();
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(asyncconn))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("rptTotalConcentrators", conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@school_yr", System.Data.SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = 2016;

                    conn.Open();
                    using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                    {

                        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                        {
                            ResultSet testy = new ResultSet();
                            testy.bldg_no = reader["bldg_no"].ToString();
                            testy.bldg_name = reader["bldg_name"].ToString();
                            testy.school_year = reader["school_year"].ToString();
                            testy.concentrator = reader["conc"].ToString();
                            resulty.Add(testy);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return resulty;
        }
```

the problem is that lblorg.Text is showing about .06 for completed milliseconds. Either `.WhenAll` doesn't work how i think, or something else is wrong. because that should take a lot longer.